# How to make ttk.Progressbar take up the entire width of a frame?

Tags: python, tkinter, progress-bar

I have a GUI that I'm working on and it's mostly coming along well after a few hiccups but one thing I can't figure out is how to make `ttk.Progressbar` take up the entire width of the frame it's been placed in.

Here's the code I use to create the progress bar:

```
    def _create_progressbar(self):
        self.progress = ttk.Progressbar(self.bottom, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, mode='determinate')
        self.progress.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)
```

I've tried a few approaches, with the latest you can see in the code with `sticky=tk.E+tk.W` but none of them seem to do anything and the bar stays narrow (highlighted in red) even though the frame it is in takes up the entire width of the parent window. Also from what I'd checked it doesn't seem like progress bar widget has `width` parameter at all.

[image]

Does anyone know how to change the width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you tell the progress bar to take up all the horizontal space of the cell, but you didn't tell the layout manager that column 0 (where the progress bar is) to take up all the available horizontal space of the frame:

```py
self.bottom.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it. I never used `weight` before but now I'll keep an eye on it.